# Is unsafe my only option to pass a reference to this method expecting a closure?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I'm using the cursive_table_view crate, and the table has a [set_on_submit](https://docs.rs/cursive_table_view/0.13.0/cursive_table_view/struct.TableView.html#method.set_on_submit) method to which you pass a closure to be executed when the user press  over a selected row in the table. The signature of said method is:

```
 pub fn set_on_submit<F>(&mut self, cb: F)
    where
        F: Fn(&mut Cursive, usize, usize) + 'static,
```

Inside the closure, I'm trying to use something that actually comes as a parameter in the function that contains this code. I simply declare that parameter as &'static, and that's all good and expected. Now of course, I've just moved the problem to the caller of my function.

```
fn my_function(param: &'static MyType) {
   let table = TableView::new();
   table.set_on_sumbit(|cur, row, index| {
        do_something_with(param);
   }
}
```

Eventually I get to a point where I have to declare my variable as static to pass it as a parameter to that function, but because I need to modify this variable before the call (and after declaration), it needs to be static mutable. Now the problem is, when I try to modify the variable, the compiler says that I can only do that with unsafe.

I believe I understand the why of everything above. The closure is going to be called upon some event in the UI, so it makes sense that this lives for as long as the entire program.

I've tried several options with Rc and read a ton about lifetimes and even threads and messages, but I felt I was blindly trying things without really understanding at some point. Where I'm at now is that I believe I understand, but I'm uncomfortable with having to go the unsafe route suggestion.

Is it avoidable? Is my pattern wrong to begin with?

I didn't want to add more code to keep the explanation agnostic to everything else, but of course I'm happy to edit if more code helps understand the issue. Also, I don't really need to modify the struct any longer by the time I've passed the reference to the closure, in case that helps find a solution down that path.

Comment: If you added `&'static` because of an error like "closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `param`," etc., consider using simply `my_function(param: MyType)` and using `move` on the closure. If you aren't sharing `param` around you don't need anything more complicated than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of references as *mostly* (excluding `&'static` and a few other cases) being for *temporary* things, especially temporary things that live only as long as a stack frame. Therefore, don't try to use references for things like user interface callbacks.

Here's how to use `std::rc::Rc` instead, which ensures that the data lives as long as needed.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

fn my_function(param: Rc<MyType>) {        // changed parameter type
    let table = TableView::new();
    table.set_on_submit(|cur, row, index| {
        do_something_with(&param);         // & enables conversion to &MyType
    }
}
```

Now, in order to *use* this, you need to arrange so your data is *owned by* the `Rc`. It is not possible to have the above sort of callback and also have `let data = MyType {...}` directly, because **the data must be owned by the `Rc`**. (However, if useful, you can initialize it and then *later* put it in the `Rc`.)

```rust
fn main() {
    // Wrap it as soon as you construct it.
    // (Or at least before you start using callbacks.)
    let my_app_data = Rc::new(MyType {
        // whatever fields or constructor...
    });

    // Call the function. `.clone()` here makes a copy of the `Rc` refcounted pointer,
    // not the underlying data.
    my_function(my_app_data.clone());
}
```

If your program uses threads, then you must use the thread-safe reference counter `std::sync::Arc` instead of `Rc`.

If you want to *modify* the data while the callback exists — whether in a callback or elsewhere — you need to also use `RefCell` (or thread-safe `std::sync::Mutex` / `RwLock`) *inside* the `Rc`, which adds a few complications.

Comment: The question suggests OP doesn't actually need shared mutation (`do_something_with` is shown to accept `&MyType` without a problem), so `RefCell` seems unnecessary here. Even `Rc` may not actually be needed based on the question (although that's more of a 50/50)

Comment: @trentcl Thanks for pointing that out; I've updated the examples. It might turn out that OP wants to mutate the data while the callback exists, though, in which case RefCell will be needed anyway even if `do_something_with` doesn't take a mutable reference.

Comment: Thank you so very much! A combination of working on this way too late in the morning hours and not fully understanding Rc made me miss the importance of the clone. I understand now what's going on and it works as expected. I must say though that the result in the project doesn't look very elegant. The foced use of Rc turns out to be a few functions down the line from where the thing that it encapsulates was originally created, so I had to modify a few other function calls and signatures to accept Rc instead of the original type.